# Problem with `org-startup-indented`

Tags: org-mode

When I set `org-startup-indented` to be `t`, I see the following error on opening any `.org` file and the error refused to go away i.e. it reappears instantly after pressing `q`.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function org-time-add)
  org-time-add(nil (0 2 0))
  org-indent-add-properties(#<marker at 1 in projects.org> 482265 (0 2 0))
  org-indent-initialize-buffer(#<buffer projects.org> (0 2 0))
  org-indent-initialize-agent()
  apply(org-indent-initialize-agent nil)
  timer-event-handler([t 0 0 200000 t org-indent-initialize-agent nil idle 0])
```

The `org` mode config which produces this error can be seen below. I observe that if remove the last line `(setq org-startup-indented t)`, the above error is not encountered. Any idea what's wrong with my configuration? Thanks!

```
   (use-package org
        :ensure org-plus-contrib
        :pin org
        :requires use-package-hydra
        :config
        (require 'ob)
        (require 'ob-async)
        (require 'org-agenda)
        (require 'org-compat)
        ; (require 'org-tempo)

        (setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil
                  org-export-babel-evaluate 'inline-only)

        (org-babel-do-load-languages
         'org-babel-load-languages
         '((emacs-lisp . t)
           (ein . t)
           (org . t)
           (makefile . t)
           (latex . t)
           (gnuplot . t)
           (R . t)
           (python . t)
           (shell . t)))

        ;; Do not evaluate org-babel source blocks during export
        (setq org-export-babel-evaluate nil)

        (setq org-startup-indented t))
```

System specifications:

```
    - OS: macOS Catalina 10.15.1
    - GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0, NS appkit-1671.20 Version 10.14.3 (Build 18D109)) of 2019-09-02
    - Org mode version 9.1.9 (release_9.1.9-65-g5e4542 @ ~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20191125/)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `(org-reload)` call at the end of my `org` mode config got rid of the issue. Reloading `org` 'upgraded' to `Org mode version 9.2.6 (9.2.6-7-g634880-elpaplus @ ~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20191125/)`
 and this version does not seem to have the issue. I also commented the line `:ensure org-plus-contrib`.

Here's the full config:

```
 (use-package org
        ;:ensure org-plus-contrib
        :pin org
        :requires use-package-hydra
        :config
        (require 'ob)
        (require 'ob-async)
        (require 'org-agenda)
        (require 'org-compat)
        ; (require 'org-tempo)

        (setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil
                  org-export-babel-evaluate 'inline-only)

        (org-babel-do-load-languages
         'org-babel-load-languages
         '((emacs-lisp . t)
           (ein . t)
           (org . t)
           (makefile . t)
           (latex . t)
           (gnuplot . t)
           (R . t)
           (python . t)
           (shell . t)))

        ;; Do not evaluate org-babel source blocks during export
        (setq org-export-babel-evaluate nil)

        (setq org-startup-indented t)

        (org-reload))
```

Comment: It solved my problem too!